# fromEvent operator with "onload" event(feat. dynamically created image element)

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to create `image` element dynamically and undertake other work after the element is loaded like below:

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = imagePath;

fromEvent(img, 'onload').subscribe(() => // do something);
```

But apparently, `fromEvent` operator never emits with `onload` event.

I saw they have discussed it in [How to load images async with RxJs and perform a method when all loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366735/how-to-load-images-async-with-rxjs-and-perform-a-method-when-all-loaded) but I'd like to know if there's any other workaround to achieve this without creating an observable myself like using `fromEvent`.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fromEvent(img, 'load').subscribe(() => // do something);
```